# JSON.Lua json.encode return nil

Tags: json, lua, null, discord, garrys-mod

I'm new to LUA and tried learning coding this language with Garrys Mod.

I want to get the messages from the Garrys Mod chat and send them into a Discord channel with a webhook.

It works, but I tried expanding this project with embeded messages. I need JSON for this and used json.lua as a library.

But as soon as I send a message I retrieve the following error message:

> attempt to index global 'json' (a nil value)

The code that causes the error is the following:

```
json.encode({ { 
        ["embeds"] = { 
            ["description"] = text, 
            ["author"] = { 
                ["name"] = ply:Nick()
            }, 
        }, 
    } }),
```

The complete code:

```
AddCSLuaFile()
json = require("json")

webhookURL = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/XXX"
local DiscordWebhook = DiscordWebhook or {}

hook.Add( "PlayerSay", "SendMsg", function( ply, text )
    t_post = {
        content = json.encode({ { 
            ["embeds"] = { 
                ["description"] = text, 
                ["author"] = { 
                    ["name"] = ply:Nick()
                }, 
            }, 
        } }),
        username = "Log",
    } 
    http.Post(webhookURL, t_post)
end )
```

I hope somebody can help me

Comment: How have you loaded the json library?

Comment: json = require("json")

Comment: Then the global variable `json` should not be nil. Perhaps you wrote `local json = require("json")` in a different file?

Comment: I've updated this thread with the whole code. Hope this can help, because the error is still not fixed

Comment: @Lesh What if you try to load json to local using `local json = require "json"`?

Comment: If I change json to local I receive the following error message `attempt to index upvalue 'json' (a nil value)`

Answer (score 1):

Garry's Mod does provide two functions to work with json.

They are:

```
util.TableToJSON( table table, boolean prettyPrint=false )
```

and

```
util.JSONToTable( string json )
```

There is no need to import `json` and if I recall correctly it isn't even possible.

For what you want to do you need to build your arguments as a table like this:

```
local arguments = {
["key"] = "Some value",
["42"] = "Not always the answer",
["deeper"] = {
  ["my_age"] = 22,
  ["my_name"] = getMyName()
},
["even more"] = from_some_variable
```

and then call

```
local args_as_json = util.TableToJSON(arguments)
```

Now you can pass `args_as_json` to your

```
http.Post( string url, table parameters, function onSuccess=nil, function onFailure=nil, table headers={} )
```

Comment: Well, now I recieve an output message in Discord, but its not formated like a normal embedded message

Comment: @Lesh Do you still need help with this?

Comment: yes, I'm sorry for late response. So basically what I've done was creating a local argument with all my JSON Table. Then I've used `util.TableToJSON` but my http.Post only contains this `http.Post(webhookURL, { content = act_msg, username = "Hook"} )`. But the output isn't formated and will return this `{"embeds":{"author":{"name":"Lesh"},"description":"test"}}`

Comment: @Lesh so you want to pretty print your json? right? `util.TableToJSON` has a second parameter, which you can set to `true` for this. You can also see more here: https://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/util/TableToJSON

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant instead of a formated json code an Embed output like [this](https://i.imgur.com/6f1z47I.png)

Comment: That sounds like some mistakes in the arguments... but not the TableToJSON function... But as I never made a discord bot myself I can't really provide help for that.  But I am glad, that I could at least help you with the json encoding